# Dogs really are VS Dogs are really

Tags: adverb-position

> Dogs **are really** our best friends.
>
> Dogs **really are** our best friends.

I know both sentences are grammatically correct, but what's the difference between them?

Comment: In "are really", really has the same meaning as very, and this construction connotes scale, like in the phrase "malamutes are really big". So in your example, dogs would be our best friends by a wide margin or to a large degree. In "really are", really has the same meaning as genuinely, and this construction connotes the removal of doubt, like in the phrase "I had never seen a chihuahua until today-- they really are small, like I had heard". In your other example, dogs would be our best friends in truth despite whatever negation of that idea came before the current sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In the second sentence more emphasis is put on "really." If you place the adverb there, you *really* want to stress what dogs are. A few more examples like that:

> People **really** should do something about the climate change! (this sounds a bit more urgent than "People should really do something... .")
>
> I was doubting him, but after he helped me in that situation, I know that he **really** is my friend. (here, by placing "really" before "is," you contrast how you used to feel about the person and how you feel about him now).

We usually place the adverb after the verb to be. So, "dogs are really our best friends" is certainly correct, but it doesn't show the emotion that "...really are..." does. "Really" expresses the degree though. But still, "...really are..." is even stronger.